# SwiftUI iOS Widget – Image after some time gets cropped

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I am creating iOS 14+ Widget using SwiftUI and I'm facing very strange situation. Problem is that I have just one "full widget" image (maybe or not its worth noting that it's downloaded from the internet but in the time of displaying its already loaded and injected as `UIImage`) in my widget which is displayed correctly like that:

[image]

But after some time and after some more iPhone unlocks BOOM, I get this:

[image]

Few observations:

- it happens with `systemLarge` family as well - the same percentage of image's width is cropped
- the image is cropped horizontally always by exactly the same percentage of width
- when my wallpaper is other than just plain black the cropped part is filled with black color as well
- the cropped part is filled with black no matter what user interface style (light/dark) I have

---

To make it easier I created minimal example which causes the error:

So, I have this `EntryView`

```swift
struct EntryView: View {

    var viewModel: EntryViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: image)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
    }
}
```

which is used as content for `Widget` itself

```swift
struct SomeWidget: Widget {

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(
            kind: xxx,
            provider: SomeWidgetTimelineProvider(xxx)
        ) { item in
            view(for: item)
        }
            .configurationDisplayName(xxx)
            .description(xxx)
            .supportedFamilies([.systemMedium, .systemLarge])
    }

    private func view(for item: Item) -> some View {
        Group {
            switch item {
            case .aaa(let xxx):
                EntryView(viewModel: xxx)
            case .bbb(let xxx):
                EntryView(viewModel: xxx)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this `Widget` is wrapped in `WidgetBundle`

```swift
@main
struct SomeWidgets: WidgetBundle {

    var body: some Widget {
        SomeWidget()
        SomeWidget()
    }
}
```

Maybe I should also show logic which is responsible for downloading the image. I use just simple `Data(contentsOf:)` synchronous method which is called on background queue and then I call `TimelineProvider`s callback on main queue:

```swift
final class SomeWidgetTimelineProvider: TimelineProvider {

    ...

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<SomeEntry>) -> Void) {
        getSomeModel { model in
            prefetchImage(for: model) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let image):
                    completion(
                        Timeline(
                            entries: [.aaa(EntryViewModel(image: image)],
                            policy: .after(Date() + 30 * 60)
                        )
                    )
                case .error(let error):
                    completion(
                        Timeline(
                            entries: [.bbb(xxx)],
                            policy: .after(Date() + 30 * 60)
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func prefetchImage(for model: SomeModel, completion: @escaping (Result<UIImage, Error>) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            guard
                let imageURL = URL(string: model.imageUrl),
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
            else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.failure(xxx))
                }
            }
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.success(image))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is, is something wrong with my layout or fetching logic? What am I missing?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: This needs a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Yrb its hard to reproduce the problem... this is what I don't get. This is exactly the code which causes the error. It just doesn't happen immediately, it happens after some time...

Comment: This code does not compile, therefore it can't be the code which causes the error. It may be pseudo code that mimics your code, but without an actual, compilable example there is no way to help.

Comment: @Yrb I don't agree with you. I described problem which causes the problem pretty in the deep. This "xxx" in my example is just simple data source logic which can be replaced in any app by whatever you want and which shouldn't have impact on causing this error. If you think you know what causes the problem and you have some idea, feel free to ask me for clarification of something specific.

Comment: @RobertDresler it seems that whatever image caching logic you have is corrupting the cache, can you try using the image by including it in the bundle and see if you still face the issue? We can't pinpoint to exact error without [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @SoumyaMahunt I don't use any caching logic, I just simple display `UIImage` downloaded using method showed in the edited post.

Answer (score 3):

Several issues are possible.

### 1. Resolution issue

The problem often stems from your widget's image resolution. The resolution of the image in pixels must correlate with the Widget's resolution in points. In the following pivot table, you can see what resolution in points (pts) some of the iPhone models use. Points are different to pixels because they change size based on PPI. 1 point is equal to 1 pixel when the resolution is `163 PPI`. This was the case for all the iPhones before the Retina era. Today, however, with `460 PPI`, the iPhone 12 Pro's 1 point is equal to 3 pixels across and 3 pixels down, or 9 total pixels.

Thus, your image size for the Medium Widget should not exceed 1092 x 510 pixels (72 pixels/inch) for iPhone 13 Pro Max. Using 4K source images for iOS Widgets is highly inappropriate.

---

| Model | Screen size (pts) | Small widget (pts) | Medium widget (pts) | Large widget (pts) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| iPhone 13 Pro Max | 428 x 926 | 170 x 170 | 364 x 170 | 364 x 382 |
| iPhone 11 | 414 x 896 | 169 x 169 | 360 x 169 | 360 x 379 |
| iPhone 8 Plus | 414 x 736 | 159 x 159 | 348 x 157 | 348 x 357 |
| iPhone 12 Pro | 390 x 844 | 158 x 158 | 338 x 158 | 338 x 354 |
| iPhone X | 375 x 812 | 155 x 155 | 329 x 155 | 329 x 345 |
| iPhone 7 | 375 x 667 | 148 x 148 | 321 x 148 | 321 x 324 |
| iPhone SE | 320 x 568 | 141 x 141 | 292 x 141 | 292 x 311 |

### 2. File format issue

Widgets images must be in 8-bit `.png` format. Images may include an alpha channel but should not include any transparent regions (i.e. alpha channel should be 100% white).

### 3. DispatchQoS.QoSClass

Use quality-of-service with the highest priority, i.e. `.userInteractive` case:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async { ... }
```

### 4. Invalid file issue

Try using a different `.png`. It is quite possible that the image you downloaded from the Internet is damaged or corrupted. An image may be corrupted due to interruption of transfer, malware/virus infection, SSD bad blocks, etc.

### 5. Cleanup

Sometimes, you have to delete/clean builds if you observe an improper functioning, indexing or slowness. If so, delete your project's build from the `~/Library/Developer/` folder. Next, in Xcode, select project's icon in Navigator panel and press <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> shortcut to clean the build.

Then, close Xcode, go to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache` directory and delete the cache.

### 6. Xcode version

Run your project on the release version of Xcode 14. Do not use betas.

Comment: Hello, even though I’m not sure if this 100% solves my problem, all points you mentioned make sense and could be possible solutions for someone or even for me.  I’m just curious, do you somewhere have the source of your first point’s table of widget resolutions? This is the first time I see something like that.

Comment: Under certain conditions, hi-rez images can freeze processing.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a very similar problem, and I would like to post my solution in here in case someone has the same one, because they will probably end up on this thread like I did.

My widgets had the feature to add custom images as widget backgrounds, and if the images were too large the widget went totally grey with redacted placeholders (I assume because the timeline provider fails to provide these large images).

So the solution was to programmatically crop the image to some predefined sizes. I found that for almost every device the max size of **1024 pixels** in either width or height was totally fine and working on every iOS version (iOS 16 is the latest version at the time this post was written). Only for **iPhone 11 & XR** (which have the same screen) the height/width of size **824 pixels** was the first value I found that works.

I wasn't able to find any documentation regarding those sizes and they may change in future iOS versions.

If you use static images which are stored in the project Assets, then use the **824** image for the **2x** scale, and the **1024** image for the **3x** scale.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let anyone know, Andy's answer has good points. Anyway, for me it seems that the problem does no longer exist on iOS 16. So maybe it was a bug in OS itself because without any changes in code the same code works on iOS 16 while not on iOS 15.